# JavaScript Updating Table data by tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to update a HTML table row, based on the tag id that is on the specfic row I clicked. I have this id known to me. In the below code If I hard code the value to update the second row (myTable.**rows[**2**]**.cells[6].innerHTML) I do get the desired results when editing the second row:

```
$(".updateItem").click(function () {
        let hours_select = document.getElementById('hoursU');
        let id = document.getElementById('itemId').value;
    

        let newItem = {
            "hours": hours_select.value
        }

        fetch(`/time/items/${id}`, {
            method: "PATCH",
            body: JSON.stringify(newItem),
            headers: { "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8" }
        })
    .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            var myTable = document.getElementById('TimeEntryTable');
            myTable.rows[2].cells[6].innerHTML = data.hours;
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    })
```

The problem is I won't always be editing rows[2], any row could be selected. I have been looking for a way of updating the row by the tag id I have since that is known in the data sent back from my response. But have not found how to do this. Something like:

```
myTable.rows["tr id" = data.id].cells[6].innerHTML = data.hours;
```

Clearly, the above line does not work. All references for editing tables seem to use indexing and not by tags. Any suggestions?

Comment: All you need to do is add the `event` parameter to the `click` handler.  That parameter contains a whole bunch of detail about the event.  `event.target` is the object that was clicked on.  See [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) (also [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) if you want really fine details).  i.e. `$(".updateItem").click(function (event) { doSomethingWithTarget(event.target) ... ` (Also see [jQuery.click](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

Answer (score 1):

Collect all the `<tr>` table rows into an array. Use `this` inside the row `click` handler to get the currently clicked row `<tr>`. Use [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to find the *row index* of the clicked row and use it to access and modify the row via `table.rows[index]`.

Here's a working demo that changes a clicked row's color and its last cell value to "Clicked!".

```js
const $rows = $('tr'),
      rows = $rows.get(),
      table = $('table').get(0);

$rows.on('click', function() {
  const row = table.rows[rows.indexOf(this)];
  row.cells[2].innerText = 'Clicked!';
  row.style.backgroundColor = 'Salmon';
});
```

```css
tr {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 75px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 11</td>
    <td>Col 12</td>
    <td>Col 13</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 21</td>
    <td>Col 22</td>
    <td>Col 23</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 31</td>
    <td>Col 32</td>
    <td>Col 33</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 41</td>
    <td>Col 42</td>
    <td>Col 43</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use querySelector to find row by id

try something like this

```
myTable.querySelector(`tr[id="${data.id}"]`).cells[0].innerHTML  = data.hours;
```